# Ejecutar procedimiento almacenado SQL-Server en laravel

Tags: laravel, sql-server, stored-procedure

Buenos días estimados necesito ayuda para ejecutar un procedimiento almacenado que esta en realizado en `sql server`.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[reg_lectura_v]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
           @codigo_ciclo int,
           @codigo_medidor int,
           @codigo_predio int,
           @codigo_tipo_servicio int,
           @numero_cuenta int,
           @lectura int,
           @cuadrilla int,
           @agente int,
           @estado_lectura nvarchar(5),
           @motivo_estado nvarchar(5),
           @observacion nvarchar(100),
           @usuario_ingreso nvarchar(15),
           @rango_maximo decimal(18,2),
           @rango_minimo decimal(18,2),
           @lectura_anterior int,
           @consumo int,
           @consumo_promedio int,
           @latitud nvarchar(80),
           @longitud nvarchar(80),
           @cont int,
           @id_archivo int,
           **@result_code int =1 output**
```

Yo estoy tratando de llamar.

```
 $lectura = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->statement("EXEC reg_lectura_v $request->codigo_ciclo,$request->codigo_medidor,$request->codigo_predio,$request->codigo_tipo_servicio,$request->numero_cuenta,'$lectura_',$request->cuadrilla,$request->agente,'$request->estado_lectura','$request->motivo_estado','$request->observacion','$request->usuario_ingreso',$request->rango_maximo,$request->rango_minimo,$request->lectura_anterior,$request->consumo,$request->consumo_promedio,'$request->latitud','$request->longitud', $request->act_medidor,$v,''");
```

Y me esta retornando error:

```
 <span class="exception_message">SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: The active result for the query contains no fields.</span>
```

Comment: Tu SP no esta completo, no? y tu llamada parece tener errores de codigo. El codigo que pusiste funciona? y que tiene tu SP?

Comment: el sp solo coloque las variables de entrada y la variable output, y no se como llamar a ese procedimiento con esa variable output alguna sugerencia

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado para ejecutar procedimientos almacenados de sql server en laravel, con parametros de entrada y salida.

1. Primero declaramos una variable tal y como se ha declarado en en el SP
   `declare @result_code as int;`
2. Luego ejecutamos el SP con todos los parámetros de entrada y salida

   ```
   EXEC reg_lectura_v $request->codigo_ciclo,$request-:codigo_medidor,$request->codigo_predio,$request->codigo_tipo_servicio,$request->numero_cuenta,'$lectura_',$request->cuadrilla,$request->agente,'$request->estado_lectura','$request->motivo_estado','$request->observacion','$request->usuario_ingreso',$request->rango_maximo,$request->rango_minimo,$request->lectura_anterior,$request->consumo,$request->consumo_promedio,'$request->latitud','$request->longitud', $request->act_medidor,$v,**@result_code OUTPUT**;
   ```
3. Finalmente realizamos un select a la variable declara para imprimir la respuesta del SP `select @result_code as RES`

EJEMPLO COMPLETO

```
$lectura = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select("declare @result_code as int ; EXEC reg_lectura_v $request->codigo_ciclo,$request->codigo_medidor,$request->codigo_predio,$request->codigo_tipo_servicio,$request->numero_cuenta,'$lectura_',$request->cuadrilla,$request->agente,'$request->estado_lectura','$request->motivo_estado','$request->observacion','$request->usuario_ingreso',$request->rango_maximo,$request->rango_minimo,$request->lectura_anterior,$request->consumo,$request->consumo_promedio,'$request->latitud','$request->longitud', $request->act_medidor,$v,@result_code OUTPUT; select @result_code as RES");
```